# Angularjs IF - ELSE condtion on checkboxes

Tags: angularjs, checkbox

i am new to Angular js i want to ask i have a case in which i have to return "YES" if the checkbox is checked or true and want to return "NO" when the value is false or unchecked.

actually my data is storing in databse in "Tinyint" 1 or 0 form i want to do when 1 occurs it shows YES any solution for this Any help will be appreciated.
Here is my html

```html
 <form class="form-horizontal">
                           <div class="form-group">
                              <label class="col-lg-2 control-label">Name</label>
                              <div class="col-lg-10">
                                 <input type="text" ng-model="rec.Name" placeholder="Name" class="form-control">
                              </div>
                           </div>
                          
                           <div class="form-group">
                              <div class="col-lg-offset-2 col-lg-10">
                                 <div class="checkbox c-checkbox">
                                    <label>
                                       <input type="checkbox" value="" ng-model="rec.isSpecial">
                                       <span class="fa fa-check"></span>is Special</label>
                                 </div>
                              </div>
                           </div>

                           <div class="form-group">
                              <div class="col-lg-offset-2 col-lg-10">
                                 <div class="checkbox c-checkbox">
                                    <label>
                       <input type="checkbox" ng-model="rec.isMultiple">
                                       <span class="fa fa-check"></span>Is Multiple</label>
                                 </div>
                              </div>
                           </div>


                           <div class="form-group">
                              <div class="col-lg-offset-2 col-lg-10">
                                 <button type="button" ng-click="add(rec)" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">ADD</button>
                              </div>
                           </div>
                        </form>
```

i need to target checkbox ismultiple and isspecial .

Comment: Read the docs... https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bcheckbox%5D
you have a `ng-true-value` and `ng-false-value` paramether

Comment: actually my data is storing in databse in "Tinyint" 1 or 0 form i want to do when 1 occurs it shows YES

Comment: a checkbox shows a tick not a caption. you can display your caption somewhere else with `ng-if` or something.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ng-true-value of ng-false-value like this:

```html
 <form class="form-horizontal">
                           <div class="form-group">
                              <label class="col-lg-2 control-label">Name</label>
                              <div class="col-lg-10">
                                 <input type="text" ng-model="rec.Name" placeholder="Name" class="form-control">
                              </div>
                           </div>
                          
                           <div class="form-group">
                              <div class="col-lg-offset-2 col-lg-10">
                                 <div class="checkbox c-checkbox">
                                    <label>
                                       <input type="checkbox" ng-model="rec.isSpecial" ng-true-value = "YES" ng-false-value="NO">
                                       <span class="fa fa-check"></span>is Special</label>
                                 </div>
                              </div>
                           </div>

                           <div class="form-group">
                              <div class="col-lg-offset-2 col-lg-10">
                                 <div class="checkbox c-checkbox">
                                    <label>
                       <input type="checkbox" ng-model="rec.isMultiple" ng-true-value = "YES" ng-false-value="NO">
                                       <span class="fa fa-check"></span>Is Multiple</label>
                                 </div>
                              </div>
                           </div>


                           <div class="form-group">
                              <div class="col-lg-offset-2 col-lg-10">
                                 <button type="button" ng-click="add(rec)" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">ADD</button>
                              </div>
                           </div>
                        </form>
```

Comment: thanx for reply .. let me give it a try

Comment: actually my data is storing in databse in "Tinyint" 1 or 0 form i want to do when 1 occurs it shows YES any solution for this